# Numpy 2D dot operation, indexing and iteration. How to optimize?

Tags: python, optimization, numpy

I need to remove this bottleneck from the code. Hope someone can help me.

I have the following iteration (extract from a nn inverse distance interpolation algorithm):

```
jinterpol=0
for w, ix in zip(wds, ixs):
        wz = np.vdot(w, z[ix])
        result[jinterpol] = wz
        jinterpol += 1
```

I've tried with removing the for loop:

```
result = np.dot(wds, z[ixs])
```

but of course it says ValueError: objects are not aligned

Can you give me some tips? Many thanks.

Shapes are:

- wds: (550800, 8)
- z: (212065,)
- z[ixs]: (550800, 8)
- ixs:(550800, 8)

and

- len(zip(distances, ixs)): 550800
- w: (8,)
- ix: (8,)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> wds = np.random.rand(550800, 8)
>>> z = np.random.rand(212065)
>>> ixs = np.random.randint(212065, size=(550800, 8))

>>> np.einsum('ij,ij->i', wds, z[ixs])
array([ 1.65069924,  3.26203701,  3.16035664, ...,  1.76963986,
        2.09727537,  1.94905991])

>>> np.vdot(wds[0], z[ixs[0]])
1.6506992361953157
>>> np.vdot(wds[1], z[ixs[1]])
3.2620370116548827
```

Comment: Great! It makes my day. Many thanks. I will be looking at np.einsum but for the moment it simply works.

Comment: On my system it gives a memory error: you are computing a huge array and the throwing away everything but the diagonal, I'd be surprised if it was advantageous in any way.

Comment: Yes, I tried np.dot(wds, z[ixs].T) as well before to ask here and it gave me a memory error.